# Node.js send data to backend with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm quite new to AJAX, so sorry for potential missunderstandings, but I'm not completely through that thing.

I'm trying a simple thing. I have a `server.js` file, which is my backend basically. Then I have a `index.html` and a `script.js`. That's all, so a very basic setup. Now, on my `script.js`, I'm getting some data (a mail address). Now I want to send that data to my backend (into the `server.js`) to work with it there. How can I do this?

I found some posts already about AJAX with node.js, but I don't get it, especially not where to receive it in my backend. I'm using express for the server by the way.

What I have in my `script.js` is:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "server.js",
            data: { mail: mail },
            success: function(data) {
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
            }
        });
```

Right so far? How can I now receive the information in my `server.js`?

There's not much in so far, just:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Can you share what you have done?

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh Sure, edited with the code from my `server.js`

Comment: put the code of server.js

Comment: Please replace your `url` part in `ajax` url must be a valid route

Comment: @Mostafa did that

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh why is not now? Do I have to use `/server.js`? `script.js` is under public folder, `server.js` just under root directory

Comment: don't use server.js you need a route and express helps with that

Comment: @DanielA.White okay, I'' try to change that, but then I still wonder how to receive my AJAX call then, so how do I get the data transfered in my, lets call it `emailReceive.js`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Note: This was written before the question was updated with the code so the field names and port numbers that I used here as examples may need to be updated with the correct values.*

Client-side code - example with jQuery:

```
$.post('/email', { address: 'xxx@example.com' });
```

(this can take optional callbacks and it returns a promise that can be used to add a success/error handler)

Server-side code - example with Express:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/email', (req, res) => {
  // you have address available in req.body:
  console.log(req.body.address);
  // always send a response:
  res.json({ ok: true });
});

app.use(express.static(dir));

app.listen(4443, () => console.log('Listening on http://localhost:4443/'));
```

This assumes that your static files (HTML, client-side JavaScript, CSS) are in the `public` directory relative to your `server.js` file.

See this for background on the JSON/form-encoding issue:

- [Which method is prefer when building API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45073560/which-method-is-prefer-when-building-api/45079695#45079695)

See this for background on serving static files:

- [How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767)

Answer (score 2):

That's actually quite simple to implement in Express.JS with the basic router:

I'm gonna give you the minified code snippets to help you get sense of how it works across browser and server.

in Front-End, you basically just want to "post" an email address to the backend:

```
$.post('/email', { email: 'howareyou@xx.com' })
```

and in Back-End(Express.JS), you should implement the basic router:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// use: app.METHOD(PATH, HANDLER)
app.post('/email/', function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email
})
```

Read more here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: and then I can just access that `email` variable in the same js-file that I have my express in?

Comment: @nameless exactly, but make sure the url is the same both in front-end and back-end

Comment: okay, but there doesn't have to be a file like `email.js`, I can just use whatever name I want, it just have to be the same?

Comment: @nameless yes, but if your program goes larger and larger, you may want to design a good modular pattern to make the whole project more managable. for example, a file "route.js" which is used to handle the routing issue:)

Answer (score 2):

First, you need a valid route to hit when the server is running. You can do this in `server.js` through express.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/mail', function(req, res) {
  var body = req.body;

  console.log('email', body.email);

  res.json({ message: 'I got the email!' });
});

var server = app.listen(3000);
```

Notice I have brought in an express middleware that will parse the body for JSON and make it available on the `req` object under `req.body`. You will need to install this dependency with `npm install --save body-parser`.

Then you need to send a `POST` request to that URL from the front-end.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/mail",
    data: { mail: mail },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('message', data.message);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
    }
});
```

Now, if you submit an email, you should see a log in your terminal that shows the email and a log in your developer console in the browser that shows the message "I got the email!"

Answer (score 0):

in server.js add this :

```
app.post('/searching', function(req, res){
 //do something with req
});
```

and in script.js :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/searching",
            data: { mail: mail },
            success: function(data) {
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a few more things to actually be able to parse the body. Add this to your server.js file.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

You need to specify a valid URL. Since you are listening on 3000. You also need to specify a route on your server as an endpoint.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http:localhost:3000/",
            data: { mail: mail },
            success: function(data) {
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
            }
        });
```

Now you need to add a route on your server. You can do so by adding this to your server.js file after all of the app.use calls

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
    // your logic here
    res.send("I am sending something back!");

})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you nedd to create a route for the Mail

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 


var app = express();
var router=app.Router();  
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');


//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // Parse request body 


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Route to check Email
router.post('/CheckEmail',(req,res)=>{
     var email=req.body.mail;   // Get email here
})

app.listen(process.env.port || 3000,()=>{
   console.log('server is running');
})
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/CheckEmail",  // post route name here
            data: { mail: mail },
            success: function(data) {
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
            }
        });
```