# Passing variables from client side to backend in Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, webstorm

I have a Node.js Express project with the files oriented like this (WebStorm IDE):

[image]

I would like to pass a variable from the marked `index.js` to `app.js` so that I can write that variable in `data.json` at the end.

I am still new to Node.js and still confused about the client/server theory. It will be much easier if there is a way to write the data directly from `index.js` to `data.json`, or any other json file, but I think that this is not possible according to previous answers. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

---

**Update:**

Issue was solved using Ajax as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105992/node-js-send-data-to-backend-with-ajax) answer :

using `$.post('/email', { address: 'xxx@example.com' });` in index.js to send data, and

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/email', (req, res) => {
  // you have address available in req.body:
  console.log(req.body.address);
  // always send a response:
  res.json({ ok: true });
});

app.use(express.static(dir));

app.listen(4443, () => console.log('Listening on http://localhost:4443/'));
```

in app.js to recieve data.

Comment: ` I think that this is not possible according to previous answers. ` It surely is possible. Just use `fs.writeFile`.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to do without your posting some code.

Comment: @JonasW. when I tried  `require('fs')` in index.js I got _require is not defined_ message, and when I looked it up, it was mentioned that we cannot use require for client side code, which I'm assuming is the index.js part.

Comment: Then you have to use Ajax to pass the data from the client to the backend

Comment: @JonasW. I'll try that, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Your index.js should have a function thats returns the variable value, like this:

```
# index.js
exports.default = () => {
  return 'my data';
}

# app.js
const dataGetter = require('./public/javascripts/index.js');
const myData = dataGetter();
```

Or, if your data is static, you can just require() the index.js every time you want.

In node.js, you should declare variables in functions, functions are the nature of Node.js ecosystem.