# How to send data from ejs templates to express server to store in a database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to *send string data from html tags on button click to express server so I can store that data in a database*.

The website basically lets users to search for movies and add movies to their list (database). It contain title, rate and description.

**search.ejs**

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs') %> 

<div class="main-content">
    <div class="heading"><h3>Search Results</h3></div>
<% if(searchData.length > 0) { %> 
    <% for( let i = 0; i < searchData.length; i ++) { %> 
<div class="movies">
    <h3 class="title"><%= searchData[i].original_title %> </h3>

    <p class="rating">(Rating: <%= searchData[i].vote_average %>) </p>

    <p class="description">Description: <%= searchData[i].overview %> </p>
    <button class="addbtn">Add to my list</button>
</div>
<% } %> 
<% } %>
<script>
    const addBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.addbtn');
    const rating = document.querySelectorAll('.rating');
    const title = document.querySelectorAll('.title')
    const description = document.querySelectorAll('.description')

    let ratingText = '', titleText = '', descriptionText = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < addBtns.length; i ++) {
        addBtns[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            titleText = title[i].textContent;
            ratingText = rating[i].textContent;
            descriptionText = description[i].textContent;
            console.log(titleText, ratingText, descriptionText);
        })

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I have managed to get the text content of the elements I want to add to database on click using JavaScript.

This is the server file but I cant figure out what routes to add when the button is clicked so it can save data.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const AddedMovie = require('./models/movies')
require('dotenv').config()

const dbURI = `mongodb+srv://ali:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.oimla.mongodb.net/${process.env.DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then (() => app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started and connected to db.')))
.catch (err => console.log(err));

//setting the view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// use static files
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));


// The movie db key 
const API = process.env.API_KEY;

//api links
const trending = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/day?api_key=${API}`

//homepage rendering code

app.get('/search', (req,res) => {
    var searchQuery = req.query.searchQuery;
    const searchAPI = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API}&query=${searchQuery}&include_adult=true`

    fetch(searchAPI)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        res.render('search', {title: 'Search results', searchData: data.results})
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('ERROR')
})
```

All solutions I have found are using forms with inputs, where they use name and access it from `req.body`.

Comment: I would recommend you start a basic example and build on top of that. [These answers to this question can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105992/node-js-send-data-to-backend-with-ajax).

Comment: Thank you for the help!